# Web scraping Python Shell Not Responding

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run this basic code but even after waiting for long, Python shell simply get stuck and i always find myself facing **'Python 3.6.5 Shell(Not Responding)'**. Please suggest.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
webdump = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(webdump,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 2):

This page is around 1MB, so spitting more than 974047 bytes (`soup.prettify()` adds more spaces and newlines) into the terminal *at once* is probably what makes it stuck.

Try printing this text line by line:

```
for line in soup.prettify().splitlines(False):
    print(line)
```